# Find all rectangles in a histogram

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, rectangles

I am sure most of you have heard about the largest rectangle in a histogram problem. -[Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-rectangular-area-in-a-histogram-set-1/)-

In my current project, I need to change this algorithm so that it **finds all rectangles which are not a smaller subset of another rectangle** in that histogram.

This is how far I am currently. But I cannot figure out how to not count the subsets in here.

```
   //time: O(n), space:O(n)
     public ArrayList<int[]> largestRectangles(int[] height) {
            ArrayList<int[]> listRect = new ArrayList<int[]>();

            if (height == null || height.length == 0) {
                return null;
            }

            Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

            int max = 0;
            int i = 0;

            while (i < height.length) {
                //push index to stack when the current height is larger than the previous one
                if (stack.isEmpty() || height[i] >= height[stack.peek()]) {
                    stack.push(i);
                    i++;
                } else {
                //add rectangle when the current height is less than the previous one
                    int p = stack.pop();
                    int h = height[p];
                    int w = stack.isEmpty() ? i : i - stack.peek() - 1;
                    listRect.add(new int[]{p,h,w});
                }

            }

            while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                int p = stack.pop();
                int h = height[p];
                int w = stack.isEmpty() ? i : i - stack.peek() - 1;
                listRect.add(new int[]{p,h,w});
            }

            return listRect;
        }
public static void main(String[] args) {

         for(int[] rect : largestRectangles(new int[]{1,2,2,3,3,2})) {
             System.out.print("pos:"+rect[0]+" height"+rect[1]+" 
         width"+rect[2]);
             System.out.println();
         }
     }
```

Comment: I actually have not heard of that problem. Could you please edit your question to include the following information: What exactly is the "largest rectangle in a histogram problem"? Does it just find the tallest rectangle? What does it do if two or more rectangles are the tallest and are the exact same height? What does it mean for a rectangle to "not be a smaller subset of another rectangle"?

Comment: I added a link for description :)

Comment: Great, thanks! That's much more clear.

Comment: Please clarify " What does it mean for a rectangle to "not be a smaller subset of another rectangle". A drawing could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to check if the new rectangle being added contains the last added rectangle; if so then simply remove the last added rectangle information from the result list before adding this new one (so confirming by height). I don't have Java IDE handy so tried in C#.

Following is the part you'll need to add in two places (please convert to java) right before your listRect.Add(new[] {p,h,w}.).

```
if (listRect.Count > 0)
{

    if (listRect[listRect.Count - 1][1] <= h)
    {
        listRect.RemoveAt(listRect.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

This is just an idea. You'll have to write logic for omitting above remove logic for histograms with 0 in them  i.e. new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 1 } etc. But logic is similar; you'll have to store a flag etc. and bypass removal of last rectangle based on its position.